# I have a design that I want to implement but can't figure out the approach in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

[see design here :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzdbZ.jpg)

Whenever I press the comment button the edittext feild along with keyboard should appear and when I click the send button the keyboard should disappear and the text sent should display in between the react and comment button

Answer (score 0):

To show keyboard you can add this when calling your alertDialog after `alertDialog.show()`:

```
final InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                input.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
alertDialogEditText.requestFocus();      
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

and to hide the keyboard add this at the end of your sendbutton code:

```
keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

to display the text:

```
containerBetweenReacAndComent.setText(alertDialogEditText.getText().toString());
```